# Apache error: "FAIL - Application at context path /tibclient could not be started"

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, maven-2, tomcat6

I am trying to deploy my maven project over Apache Tomcat 6.0. I am successfully able to deploy it from command prompt using mvn tomcat:deploy. When i try to access my application it gives 404 error over webpage.

In my tomcat manager I could see that there was an option Start the application, when hit "start" it give me "FAIL - Application at context path /tibclient could not be started" message.

I am using Eclipse and I am not clear on how to deploy maven project over apache tomcat. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<web-app version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Tibapp Client</display-name>

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/tibclient</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>





    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

And my POM.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.tibapp</groupId>
<artifactId>TibClient</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Tib - Client -dhruv</name>

<properties>
    <!-- Spring version -->
    <version.spring>3.0.6.RELEASE</version.spring>

    <!-- Spring Third Party dependencies -->
    <version.aopalliance>1.0</version.aopalliance>

    <!-- Third Party dependencies -->
    <version.standard.taglibs>1.1.2</version.standard.taglibs>
    <version.commons.logging>1.1.1</version.commons.logging>



</properties>

<dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Third Party dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>${version.aopalliance}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>${version.standard.taglibs}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${version.commons.logging}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import Spring dependencies, these are either from community or versions 
        certified in WFK2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other community dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>Tib Client</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Force Java 6 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Deployment on apache tomcat -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <server>myserver</server>
                <path>/tibclient</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the TomCat log file?  Usually, if a web app fails to deploy, its because something went wrong.  That something is usually accompanied by a stack trace.

Comment: I dont think so as I haven't touched any tomcat files.

Comment: @JohnHaager: While creating maven project in eclipse I choose the maven project under Nexus Indexer with group ID org.jboss.spring.archetype, artifact id spring-mvc-webapp and version 1.0.0.CR3. Does that make any difference? I wanted spring mvc architecture and this was closest to my need.

Comment: That might be an issue, but without consulting the catalina.out file in TomCat, there is no way to know what went wrong with the deployment.

Comment: @JohnHaager: I see in the tomcat log file that it is not accepting the servlet dependencies. I tried different version of dependency but same problem                                  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>                                                      INFO: validateJarFile(C:\apache\apache tomcat\webapps\tibclient\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency for the `javax.servlet-api` API should be scope of `provided`.  The Servlet API is already included in TomCat.  Including it in your web application will cause a class loading error because the version in your WAR and the version in TomCat are "not the same" due to ClassLoader restrictions.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <!-- The Servlet API is provided by Tomcat -->
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```